# Throwing an exception while constructing object during a throw?

Tags: c++, exception

I have an exception class:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
    MyException( char* message )
        : message_( message )
    {
        if( !message_ ) throw std::invalid_argument("message param must not be null");
    }
};
```

And at my throw site:

```
try {
    throw MyException( NULL );
}
catch( std::exception const& e ) {
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

(code was not compiled, so please excuse any errors)

I'm wondering what will happen when I throw from a constructor while constructing due to another throw. I assume this is legal, and the catch will end up catching a `std::invalid_argument`, and the previous exception thrown (`MyException`) will be ignored or cancelled out.

My goal with this design is to enforce invariants in my exception class. `message_` should never be NULL, and I don't want to have if conditions to check if it is null in my `what()` overload, so I check them in the constructor and throw if they are invalid.

Is this correct, or is the behavior different?

Comment: As long as you catch it somewhere ... have you considered using `const std::string& message` so this is a non-issue?

Comment: If you derive from std::runtime_error you don't need to store the message yourself. Pass the mssage to the constructor of std::runtime_error. Note: Some popular but erroneous implementations allow you to pass the message to std::exception unfortunately this is not standard compliant and will cause problems when porting.

Comment: @LokiAstari I don't use `std::runtime_error` (even though I'd like to) because it requires the complete `what()` string to be formed during construction. I like to post-pone that string processing until `what()` is called, so I use `std::exception` for this purpose.

Comment: @RobertDailey: I don't understand what you are talking about. std::exception does not have support for lazy evaluation of what string. PS. I also think that is a false optimization.

Comment: @LokiAstari You are misunderstanding. I simply post-pone executing my string building logic until what() is called. std::runtime_error stores a string internally, and *requires* one in its constructor. This pretty much forces you to build the string for what() when you construct your exception object. Make sense?

Comment: @RobertDailey: Then update the quesstion with `code` as your English description still makes no sense.

Comment: @LokiAstari Sorry I couldn't be more clear. Hopefully this will help: http://pastebin.com/zYZ1p3x9

Comment: @RobertDailey: You should post that here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LokiAstari Want me to hold your hand while you cross the street, and do your dishes too? Come on man, seriously. Take it or leave it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you intend to throw (in this case `MyException`) must be successfully constructed *before* it can be thrown. So you're not throwing it yet, since it hasn't been constructed.

So this will work, throwing the exception from within `MyException`'s constructor. You won't trigger the "throwing an exception while handling an exception causes `std::terminate`" issue.

Comment: I was trying to find this in the standard, but I didn't see anything. Is this specific case mentioned in the 2003 standard?

Comment: @RobertDailey: No; why would it be? Before `throw` can execute, it must first successfully evaluate its expression. And until `throw` executes, nothing has been thrown yet. That expression didn't successfully evaluate, so that `throw` never happened. It's the inevitable consequence of many separate parts of C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Your assumption is correct but I don't buy the argument. One could argue (not that i am) that the throw has been initiated as soon as any part of the `throw statement` has been started (the throw statement includes the throw expression)` ie after you cross the `sequence point` from the last statement. Luckily the standard is explicit on the issue see: 15.1.7 (in n3376)

Answer (score 3):

### 15.1 Throwing an exception n3376

#### Paragraph 7

> If the exception handling mechanism, after completing evaluation of the expression to be thrown but before the exception is caught, calls a function that exits via an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1).

This means that until the constructor (of the object being thrown in this case) completes nothing special is going to happen. But after the constructor completes any other uncought exception will result in `terminate()` being called.

The standard goes on to provide an example:

```
struct C
{
       C() { }
       C(const C&) { throw 0; }
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw C();   // calls std::terminate()
  }
  catch(C) { }
}
```

Here terminate is called because the object is first created. But then the copy construction is called to copy the exception to the holding location (15.1.4). During this function call (copy construction) an uncaught exception is generated and thus terminate is called.

So your code as shown should work as expected.

- Either: A `MyException` is generated with a good message and thrown
- Or: A `std::invalid_argument` is generated and thrown

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check invariants that should always be true, you should use assertions. Exceptions are meant for unusual situations that are expected to happen, like corner cases or bad user input.

If you use exceptions to report bugs in your code, you could accidentally hide them with catch(...). This is especially important if you are writing library code, because then you never know if other people might catch and ignore the exception, even if it means that the system has reached an invalid state.

Another advantage of assertions is that you can completely disable them if you want, such that they will no longer incur any performance penalties. This allows you to be really paranoid with those checks in your debug builds and still have a lightning fast release build.

Comment: The disadvantage of assertions is that they are generally always disabled at run-time. There are times where even though it's something that should always be true, you still want to check it at run-time, even in release mode.

Comment: If a programmer wants to hide all exceptions with `catch(...)`, then that's just bad programming practice. You might as well argue against `assert` because that's generally implemented as a call to exit (or some variant), and I could register a function to be called at exit that just jumps back into normal execution and hide errors that way. You cannot defend against a programmer who has access to the code and is working against you.

Comment: You do not have to use the standard assert() macro, you can also define your own. That way you can have assertions that should be disabled in release builds and others that should remain.

If you throw an exception, then it should be a documented part of the interface and whoever calls your function or constructor that can throw the exception has to think about how to handle it. The case that the OP described cannot be handled in any reasonable way other than telling the user that the program has a bug and crashed. If there is no reasonable way of handling it, it should not be an exception.

Comment: There is always a reasonable way of handling things. I have a program that searches a game tree to a certain depth. Sometimes, I get into an invalid state from which there seems to be no recovery. However, I do that search on a copy of my real data (the search naturally involves lots of copying). If I get into such a state, I could use assertions (the state must always be valid!), or I could throw an exception. I chose to throw an exception, because my way of handling it is to simply report the error and return the results from the search at depth - 1. I defined depth=0 as "random result".

Comment: That same program logs into a server to play the game. I could use an "always in" assert that terminates the program on something like "socket closed unexpectedly" or "server sent invalid data". That last one means that I cannot trust my connection to be valid and I have no way of knowing where one message starts and another ends. I use exceptions because my behavior is close the socket, wait 10 seconds, and reconnect to the server. Not handling an exception is the same as calling terminate, but you give users the option to handle it. I don't want to decide that an error must always be fatal.

Comment: You describe something very different here. The situations in your case are things that you eventually expect to happen and that your program should be able to handle gracefully. Those are things that the caller of your functions should think about. The OP described a situation where someone (himself or a library user) uses his API in an incorrect way, i.e. this should be impossible to ever reach unless there is some serious bug in the code. This is the kind of situation that assertions were made for.